# Connect Filebeat to Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, filebeat

I want to use Filebeat to read the log from the server and stream it on Apache Flink. Right now we are using Filebeat -> Kafka ->Flink .

I want to remove Kafka and want to make it Filebeat -> Flink

Appreciate your response/suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a custom source connector. For the Table API, this is detailed out in https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/sourcessinks/. You can also read up on FLIP-27, which describes the Source interfaces. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-27%3A+Refactor+Source+Interface